# Get YouTube live status

Tags: php, youtube, google-api

I am just wondering if it is possible to get the status from a user on YouTube with php or something similar, and check if he/she is live right now.

Like you can put in a little div in the corner of your website with 'We are live right now', a popup or something similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with the YouTube Live Streaming API.
Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/).